# Ask for using a comma

Tags: grammar

As winter approaches, the groundhog becomes so ***fat*** ***it*** can hardly move.

My question is Why is there no comma between fat and it. Can I say "As winter approaches, the groundhog becomes so ***fat, and it*** can hardly move"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma isn't necessary. The expression has a subordinator, "that" elided. It could be expressed as

> The groundhog becomes so fat **that** it can hardly move.

Your paraphrase with "so fat, and it can hardly move" is not correct, because it gives a different meaning to "so", and unlinks it from the result. That is, putting in a comma and "and" make the "so" merely an adjective meaning "very", while making "it can hardly move" an independent clause.

The word "so" followed by an adjective and a result clause is explained here:
[English Study Page "so + adjective + that"](https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/so-that-vs-such-that/)

"We can use 'so' with 'adjectives /adverbs + that' to explain the result. ... However, using 'that' is not necessary."

Comment: Thanks so much! I have one more question that why "that" is elided in the sentence?

Comment: There isn't a particular reason, it's just an optional word, a subordinator, that makes what follows it a subordinate clause. I mentioned it to clarify the structure of the expression, but it's still a subordinate clause even if "that" is omitted. It is probably more common to leave it out than to include it.

Comment: got it! Thanks again!

Comment: I don't like the statement that the paraphrase is "not correct." It ***is*** correct. It just changes the meaning (as you explain). But it reads as if you're saying it's ungrammatical, which isn't the case. It would be far clearer if you wrote something like *while your paraphrase is grammatical, it changes the meaning*.